# use MultiArray in rosserial

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All

Can we use std_msgs MultiArray in rosserial?
I'm trying following code, but it doesn't work.
The topic has no data.

We are using rosserial of revision 133:db62c6309a50 tip.
Does anyone have suggestion?

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16MultiArray.h>

#include <WProgram.h>
#include <Servo.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

std_msgs::Int16MultiArray thermo;
ros::Publisher thermo_pub("thermo", &thermo);

char dim0_label[] = "thermo";
void setup()
{
  nh.initNode();
  thermo.layout.dim = (std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension *)
  malloc(sizeof(std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension) * 2);
  thermo.layout.dim[0].label = dim0_label;
  thermo.layout.dim[0].size = 8;
  thermo.layout.dim[0].stride = 1*8;
  thermo.layout.data_offset = 0;
  thermo.data = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*8);
  nh.advertise(thermo_pub);
}

void loop()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    thermo.data[i] = analogRead(i);
  }
  thermo_pub.publish( &thermo );   
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(500);
}
```

the rostopic echo returns

```
tsuda@tsuda-laptop:~$ rostopic echo /thermo
layout:
 dim: []
 data_offset: 0
data: []
---
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10988/use-multiarray-in-rosserial/) by [atsushi_tsuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/981/atsushi_tsuda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2011-08-23

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-23**:
You can also indent a code block by 4 spaces to get it formatted nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you set the length of your data:

```
  thermo.layout.dim_length = 1;
  thermo.data_length = 8;
```

This is necessary since we are using plain old arrays, and not vectors (which would wreak havoc on your AVR by copying, malloc'ing, and other stuffs).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-08-24**:
Great, if you could click on the checkmark next to my answer it will mark this question as answered. Thanks!

**Comment by [atsushi_tsuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/981/atsushi_tsuda/) on 2011-08-23**:
Thanks. it does work!!

**Comment by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on 2019-04-24**:
Is `data_length` multiplication of all dimension size?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I spent a day to debug this code. It keeps generate "Lost sync with device, restarting..." .  Eventually get rid of line `thermo.layout.dim_length = 1;` fix my problem. Not quite sure what is happen here. I did not have enough time to investigate this.  If anyone know the reason, please reply the post.  thanks

---

Originally posted by [jayson ding](https://answers.ros.org/users/492/jayson-ding/) with karma: 29 on 2014-05-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) on 2014-06-06**:
Very glad you posted this. I had the same issue. I'm using an arduino uno btw. If I figure out the reason for this, I'll post as well.

**Comment by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on 2019-04-24**:
`dim_length` value should be your array dimension - 1. So in single dimension array, `dim_length` should be 0, the default number.